# SQL Select from DB where column like but doesn't start with '*'?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a DB as follows:

```
        name                ||        Country       ||   code
     Los Angeles                   United States          LAX
***Additional Services***         United Kingdom          999V
     New York                      United States          NYC
```

I want to select all values in the three columns that match a term but hide the ones that start with '*'. This is my sql to select any value from the three columns, I just need to add the part to skip the values that start with *.

```
SELECT code, name, Country FROM city_codes WHERE CONCAT(code, name, Country) LIKE '%$term%' ORDER BY name ASC
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add to the `where` clause

```
and name not like '*%'
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, how about this?

```
SELECT code, name, Country
FROM city_codes
WHERE CONCAT(code, name, Country) LIKE '%$term%' and 
      code not like '*%' and name not like '*%' and country not like '*%'
ORDER BY name ASC;
```